# asp.net autocomplete problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i added autocomplete extender its working fine but the suggestion list half bottom is not showing because its exceed the length of the div containing textbox

thank you,

Comment: Did you try styling the `<div>` with `overflow: visible`?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any screen shot? Normally it extent to bottom of your screen.